# Sound detection using JavaScript on the client hardware

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web music application, I want to be able to pause  the music if other applications are playing and resume when there is no other sounds playing on the client hardware. How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: The browser is unaware of other sounds being played on the system.  My intuition is that you can't do this in a browser.  It would likely need to be feature of a native application.  (e.g. Think of something like Spotify where you can install a native app which can take complete control of the system if needed.)

Comment: I agree with @Wyck, My advice: tell your customer to just pause the music themselves

Comment: @Wyck: I hope can't able for listening sound from another tab, otherwise is critical bug